# Django (1.9) Watson index Django Tagging TagField

Tags: django, search, indexing, django-tagging, django-watson

How can I index a field that is managed by the [Django Tagging](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-tagging) (v0.4.5) TagField manager?

The tags are all working correctly and [Watson](https://github.com/etianen/django-watson) (v1.2.1) is indexing the models and returning results from searching the char and text fields as it should but not if the search term is a tag.

The registering is done in an AppConfig as documented:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.apps import AppConfig
from watson import search as watson

class TeamConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'team'
    def ready(self):
        Team = self.get_model("Team")
        watson.register(Team, fields=("title_text", "tagline", "description", "tags"))
        Member = self.get_model("Member")
        watson.register(Member)
```

and the `Team` model that has the `tag` TagField field is all good:

```
import blahs
...
from watson import search as watson
from tagging.fields import TagField
...

class Team(models.Model):
    pub_date = models.DateField('date published', auto_now_add=True)
    title_text = models.CharField('Name', max_length=200, blank=False,
    ...
    tags = TagField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Active?', default=True)
```

Anyone got any idea how to get the field indexing same as a char or text field please?

Thanks so much
Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ripped out Django Tagging, created my own model of 'tags' simply with a date and a name string and then threw a ManyToMany field in each of the models to be tagged. Needs some extra logic to update that pool of tags but that seems easy enough with a loop to test if tag.name.exists() upon save for the associated models.

Having that simple field type also made Django Material form way easy to add a selector for the static pool of tags too so win win.

Would still like to know if anyone has a way of returning text through a model manager as I've only been learning python and django on/off for a few months and really loving it so want to do things proper like.